# C strange stat st_mode

Tags: c, unix, stat

I am printing the result of `S_ISDIR(info->st_mode)` and `S_ISREG(info->st_mode)` over a directory that contains dynamic libraries with `.so` extension and the result is quite surprising, `S_ISREG` returns `0` while `S_ISDIR` returns 1.

I am a bit confused...

The code:

```
DIR *dir;
if ((dir = opendir (dirname)) != NULL) {
  struct dirent *ent;
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    struct stat info;
    stat(ent->d_name, &info);
    printf("file: %s, S_ISREG: %d, S_ISDIR: %d", ent->d_name, S_ISREG(info.st_mode), S_ISDIR(info.st_mode));
  }
}
closedir(dir);
```

The output looks like:

```
file: ., S_ISREG: 0, S_ISDIR: 1
file: zyva.so, S_ISREG: 0, S_ISDIR: 1
file: .gitignore, S_ISREG: 1, S_ISDIR: 0
file: .., S_ISREG: 0, S_ISDIR: 1
file: plugin-app, S_ISREG: 0, S_ISDIR: 1
file: chat.so, S_ISREG: 0, S_ISDIR: 1
```

*plugin-app* is also an executable so it's also a regular file...

Comment: I think your code will only work if `dirname` is `"."`.  Otherwise you have to concatenate `dirname` and `ent->d_name` before calling `stat`.

Comment: Did the `stat()` call even work?  You're not checking the return value.

Comment: Yeah, looks like for all entries except `"."`, `".."`, and `".gitignore"` (which are likely present in both places), you're always getting the stale result of the previous (misdirected) `stat` call.

Comment: You should use `S_ISLNK` to detect symbolic links.

Comment: @RSahu `stat` follows symlinks so there shouldn't be any.

Comment: @Art, it's been a while since I worked with these. Where else may one use `S_ISLNK`?

Comment: @RSahu `lstat` is just like `stat` but doesn't follow symlinks.

Comment: @Art. Thanks. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't check the return value of `stat()`.  I'll bet if you do so, you find that it failed.  In that case, the `struct stat` is not filled in, so it just contains uninitialized garbage (or the result of a previous successful call).

Why did it fail?  I bet you find that `errno == ENOENT`.  Note that `ent->d_name` only contains the *name* of the file, not the *path*, so when you try to `stat` it, it's interpreted as a path relative to the current working directory.  Unless `dirname` is the directory you're already in, you're having `stat` look for these files in the wrong place, so it's no wonder they aren't found.

Either `chdir(dirname)` before doing your `stat`s, or else construct the full path in a separate buffer by prepending `dirname/` to the filename (make sure to check the lengths to ensure that you do not overrun your buffer).

Comment: ...or use `fstatat`; this is pretty much exactly what it's for.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley What a strange but useful call!  I had never heard of that.  Thanks.  (Looks like a typo for `fstat`, though. :-) )

Comment: Never heard about it too! Is there a way to get a filedescriptor from a `DIR *`? Or should I also open the directory with standard `open` and call `fstatat`?

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto: You use `open(2)` with the `O_PATH` flag. I don't think there is a portable way to extract the file descriptor from a `DIR *`.

Comment: Ok thanks I sure have learned something today!
Do you know what is more efficient between using `fstatat` or `chdir`?

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto: `fstatat` is probably slightly more efficient since you save a system call and an extra path lookup (`namei` in traditional kernel jargon).  But a modern kernel would have that cached anyway.